# Renewing Enterprise CA certificate

Tags: windows, certificate-authority, server, active-directory

I have just renewed my Root CA certificate and having issues renewing my Enterprise CA certificate.
My setup is the Root CA is offline with online issuing CA server.
When I do the renewal nothing happens and I get the following in the Event logs

A certificate in the chain for CA certificate for Enterprise CA has expired.  A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file. 0x800b0101 (-2146762495 CERT_E_EXPIRED).

A certificate in the chain for CA certificate 0 for xxxx Enterprise CA has expired.  A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file. 0x800b0101 (-2146762495 CERT_E_EXPIRED).

I am renewing with the same private and public keys, would changing help or do I need to remove the expired certificates first.

Certificate 0 & 1 are exspired and 2 is going to exspire soon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never ever renew CA with same key pair. Always renew with new key pair. This eliminates a problem with ambiguous chains.

If I understand correctly, you have an offline Root CA and Enterprise Subordinate CA. When you renew CA certificate on subordinate, nothing visually happens, because the whole process is manual.

Once you selected `Renew CA certificate` on your Enterprise CA, a request file is generated (often placed in a root of system drive). You have to turn on your root CA, submit this request to root CA and approve it (your root CA will place request in pending requests for review and manual approval). Once issued, you have to copy signed subordinate CA certificate from root back to Sub CA. On Sub CA, in elevated command prompt run:

```
certutil -installCert
net stop certsvc && net start certsvc
```

Ensure that renewed root and subordinate CA certificates and CRLs are copied to defined distribution points.

Comment: Hi Crypt32, Thanks for the advice working perfectly I have renewed my certificate.